# How do use upload function for mail merge with Word

Tags: upload, printmerge

After many researchs on Internet, I have not found an answer to how to use the upload function, in order to do a mail merge based on an existing Word document.

Print/Merge document has an option to upload a .docx word file. But I have not figured out how to use it.

Is is possible to create a Word document and somehow add the tokens directly in this document? And then do the merge via the upload?
Thanks for your help.
(Drupal 7.67 & Civi 5.7.0)

Answer (score 1):

There's two different things:

1. Mail Merge, which is a native feature of word.
2. Print/Merge document, with output as a word document, which is a feature of CiviCRM. (I'm not sure it has the ability to "upload" a word document. If it does I'm not familiar with it, but see below.)

For the first one, you would want to do a contact export in csv format, and then from within MS Word do your mail merge as you would with any excel data source.

For the second one, inside CiviCRM:

1. Go to Administer - CiviMail - Message Templates and create a new template.
2. In the HTML section, copy/paste from MS Word into the box using the Paste-From-Word icon.
3. Then you will need to replace your tokens with the civicrm versions of the tokens, using the dropdown.
   [image]
4. Then when you do a contact search you can choose Print/Merge document from the actions dropdown on the search results page and choose your template and MS Word as the output format.

Comment: Hi Demerit. Thanks for your quick answer. I was not aware of the Paste-From-Word option. I will test in the coming days, and provide feed-back.
Concerning the upload feature at the top of the Print/Merge window, is there a documentation somewhere on how the feature works? My idea would be to create a Word document directly in Word with the requested tokens, and then upload this document to do the merging. Would this be possible?

Comment: Ah I never noticed that upload before. I don't see any documentation but looking at the code yes that seems to be how it's supposed to work.